# Linux: Program A runs Program B that kills A, replaces A, and restarts A -- problems with inherited open file descriptors

Tags: linux, process, parent-child, auto-update

I have a server process, and this server process can be given a command to update itself.  What it does is store the update and then use system() to run an update script in the background.  The update script kills the parent process, deletes the binary, replaces it, and then restarts it.

The restarted process has failed for various reasons as I have tried to debug it, but this time, it's because a TCP port I'm trying to allocate is already in use.  I'm guessing that the child process inherits the open port, which is then inherited by the updated server process, and as a result, the port isn't free for the process to allocate it again.

The way the update script is launched is this:

```
system("/usr/local/bin/update_script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Then the script does this:

```
killall server_process
rm /usr/local/bin/server_process
cp /tmp/update/server_process /usr/local/bin
server_process > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Any suggestions on how I might make this work?  Is there some way I can detach the update script so that the server process is no longer its parent before it performs the update?  Or make the child process not inherit any of the parent's resources?

Thanks.

Addendum:  A solution would be to set `FD_CLOEXEC` on every open file descriptor.  Unfortunately, some of those fd's are buried in libraries, which I'd have to seriously hack up in order to make them set `FD_CLOEXEC`.  Somehow, I need to make `FD_CLOEXEC` the default.  Or I need to do something drastic, like iterate over all open fd's (how?) and set `FD_CLOEXEC`.

Comment: Hey pass the `SIGNAL` `9` or in other words `SIGKILL` instead of `SIGTERM`. By default, `killall` is passing `SIGTERM`

Comment: @Suku Good idea, except that I'd like the process to shut down cleanly.  I actually have a signal handler in the server process that catches SIGTERM and does a little cleanup on the way out.

Comment: ok. then it is better to put a sleep (`sleep 10`) between `killall server_process` and your `rm /usr/local/bin/server_process`. So can make sure that your initial script is getting enough time get shutdown gracefully.

Comment: @Suku Actually, the process of updating involves more than what I showed, and it takes several seconds longer than it takes for the server process to shut down normally.  The problem is that the shell process inherits the server process's open file descriptors, which are then inherited again by the respawned server process.

Comment: Throwing out there two ideas. 1- Making an upstart or sysinitv job for your server process may allow you to start it indirectly and 'cut' the parent child relationship. 2- Another idea is to use inotify (or some of its utilities like inoticoming or incron) to automatically start your server process when a specific file is created/touched in some location. <http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html> <http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/init.5.html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way the update script is started.

```
switch(fork()) {
case -1: /* error */
    break;
default: /* parent */
    break;
case 0: /* child */
    for (i=3; i<1000; i++) close(i);
    system("/usr/local/bin/update_script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1");
    exit(0);
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of that.  I almost missed the critical line you put in there where you indiscriminately close all fd's from 3 upwards.  Assuming that closing an already-closed fd doesn't cause any problems (i.e. crash), then this would work perfectly.  I can't really test it now (I found another solution), but I'm going to mark this as the chosen answer because it's simple and direct.